# javascript - replace method - regex escape necessary?

Tags: javascript

When I do this, trying to remove all non-alpha characters,

```
var word = "thi^s";
var word2 = word.replace(/[^a-zA-z]/g, "");
console.log(word2);
```

Why is the caret slipping through? I'm supposed to escape it?

Comment: `A-z` actually means `A` (U+0041) to `z` (U+007A), which includes `^` (U+005E).

Comment: Its not clear what do you want your final output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uppercase/lowercase expression is incorrect. I'm assuming this error is throwing off the regular expression engine. Replace `a-zA-z` with `a-zA-Z`

Use

```
var word = "thi^s";
var word2 = word.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
console.log(word2);
```

Which will produce: `this`

Edit: As [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) stated, `A-z` actually means `A` (U+0041) to z (U+007A), which includes `^` (U+005E).

Comment: So my flaky shift key caused all this trouble. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

anything written inside `[]` is character class. `[^a-zA-Z]` means anything other than a-z or A-z.

Use `\^` for its literal meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
var word = "thi^s";
var word2 = word.replace(/[\^a-zA-Z]/g, "");

console.log(word2); //=> ""
```

Since caret `^` has a special meaning inside character class.

`[^a-zA-Z]` means match anything except upper case and lower case English alphabets.

Comment: @user1544556 is looking to replace the caret (non alphabetical chars) with nothing, not to replace everything with nothing.

Comment: @ZebRawnsley: This wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: He asked why was the caret slipping through.

Comment: In fact OP wrote: `Why is the caret slipping through?` which means probably OP wants to replace caret as well..